# Tree coordinates matching on a 2d plane in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to automate matching of 2d sets of tree locations in R.

Data is coming from ultrasonic trilateration and electronic caliper measurement of trees. Each measurement contains tree trunk center location relative to plot center and tree diameter (average of 2 perpendicular caliper measurements).

Ultrasonic trilateration has a short range (about 15-20m) and so multiple overlapping plots need to be made. Goal is to combine together multiple overlapping plots to cover a larger area as seen on the image below. Realistically all tree locations and diameters will have some error and wont match perfectly. Also the plot centers might not be equal distance apart and in the worst case it is also not known which plot is adjacent to which other plot.
[image: Multiple plots to cover the area]

I think only matchable data is tree diameters and distances between trees. Angles between trees wont be the same when viewed from a different location. Also a minimum of three overlapped points between sets are needed. For example plot 1 has three trees that are also present on plot 2 and could be matched. However plot 5 below has 8 overlapping trees and should be matched first due to theoretically more accurate matching. So perhaps create some kind of ranking to decide which plots to match first.

[image: Matching by distance]

So my logic so far:

1. Calculate distance matrices for all plots perhaps with dist() function from Stats pkg.
2. Choose random plot. First plot in list I guess.
3. Compare that plots distance matrix with all other matrices to find approximate distance matches. Although I think only (n^2)-n distances need to be compared for each plot (n is tree count on plot) as that should be the number of unique tree pairs.
4. After finding tree pairs with similar distance we compare diameters of those trees. For example in the image above for plot 1 and 2 we would have three pairs forming: AB, BC, CA.
5. If the distance and diameters of trees A,B and C on both plots are close enough (lets say no more than 10% different) then we declare that those trees are in fact the same trees and we count those as matches.
6. Then we count matches for all plot pairs (should be half of total plot count permutations) and choose the pair with most matches. For 12 plots we get 66 pairs.
7. Merge best matched pair by somehow minimizing distance between matched points?
8. Remove duplicated trees by averaging coordinates and diameters.
9. Take this new set of points and match next best plot using steps 3 to 8 until all plots have been combined to one.
10. Final adjustment? After all matches have been found, repeat step 7 but with all plots together to minimize errors for all plots combined.

Would this task even be feasible in R on an average PC if lets say we would have a maximum of 30 plots and on average 100 trees per plot? I think about 24 million comparisons are needed to compare distances for first two plots which does not sound too bad. But as the combined set grows larger the number of distances will also get huge quick. So perhaps find matching diameters first and calculate distances for those trees only?

Since this is such a complex task I would first like some general opinions and advice if my proposed strategy could work and if it could be done smarter. I cant implement most of those proposed steps anyway so I would probably have to make dedicated posts to tackle those problems.